# geeglm correlation matrix interpretation

Tags: interpretation, covariance-matrix, generalized-estimating-equations

I chose an exchangeable var-cov mmatrix for my `geeglm`

```
library(geepack)

data("muscatine")

gee2 <- geeglm(numobese ~ gender + occasion, id = id,
               data = muscatine, family = binomial(),
               corstr = "exchangeable")

summary(gee2)
```

The variance covariance matrix that I get after fitting this model is

```
gee2$geese$vbeta
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  0.00421 -2.01e-03 -1.09e-03
[2,] -0.00201  3.92e-03  1.19e-05
[3,] -0.00109  1.19e-05  5.32e-04
```

I was expecting something like this because I chose corstr = "exchangeable"

```
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  1           rho       rho
[2,] rho          1         rho
[3,] rho          rho       1
```

same values in off-diagonal cells. I like to know where I am wrong, thanks.

Comment: This is the covariance matrix of the *estimates.*  The exchangeability applies to the *error terms.*

Comment: @whuber, sorry for asking a very basic question, Then how do I extract the final variance-covariance matrix of the residuals after fitting the model using geeglm , is it `gee2$geefit$alpha` ?

Comment: I can't tell you because I haven't employed that package.  I would begin by reading its documentation.

Comment: @whuber, Gracias Whuber Gracias.